# Meteor creating selection and then find selected state

Tags: meteor, selected

I'm new to Meteor and building a demo site to play around with it but noticed an interesting problem. In the code below I'm trying to create a selection box and populate it with years for a user's date of birth. The helper for that seems straight forward. The issue is tying the query of Mongo to it so I can display the selection chosen. What I ended up creating is horrible. Multiple calls to the db and then the isSelected helper runs again and spins over everything needlessly.

Clearly there must be a way to create the selection and at the same time find the selected option in one pass preferably w/o an additional db call. But helper only returns one value. Maybe returning an array with year and selection state? I don't think I've seen that on anything I've read yet but it's early days with Meteor for me still, I know nothing. Anyone have ideas on how to create this with great performance? Thanks

```
<template name="accountProfile">
    {{#with accountDetails}}

    Other bits of data using accountDetails here

    <li>
        {{> userDateOfBirth}}
    </li>
    {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="userDateOfBirth">
        <select name="userDateOfBirthYear">
        {{#each displayYears}}
            <option value="{{this}}" selected="{{isSelected}}">{{this}}</option>
        {{/each}}
        </select>
</template>


Template.accountProfile.helpers({
    'accountDetails': function(){
        var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
        var userProfileCreated = User.findOne({ createdBy: currentUser });
        return userProfileCreated;  
    }
});

Template.userDateOfBirth.helpers({
    'displayYears': function(){
        var listOfYears = [];
        var numberOfYearsToList = 120;
        for (var i = numberOfYearsToList-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            listOfYears[i] = 2015 - i;
        };
        return listOfYears;
    },
    'isSelected' : function(){
        var currentUser = Meteor.userId();
        var userProfileCreated = User.findOne({ createdBy: currentUser });
        var numberOfYearsToList = 120;
        for (var i = numberOfYearsToList-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(2015 - i + " " + this);
            if((this) == moment(new Date(userProfileCreated.dateOfBirth)).format("YYYY")){
                return "selected";
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `accountDetails` already returns the profile of current user, you can access its `dateOfBirth` even inside `displayYears` context by using `../` (access parent data context), which helps you to avoid multiple queries to the DB.

```
<template name="accountProfile">
  {{#with accountDetails}}
    //- Other bits of data using accountDetails here
    <li>
      {{> userDateOfBirth}}
    </li>
  {{/with}}
</template>

<template name="userDateOfBirth">
  <select name="userDateOfBirthYear">
    {{#each displayYears}}
      <option value="{{this}}" selected="{{isSelected ../dateOfBirth}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>

Template.userDateOfBirth.helpers({
  'isSelected' : function(dateOfBirth) {
    if (this == moment(new Date(dateOfBirth)).format("YYYY")) {
      return "selected";
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.